# AWS DMS Replication Task Swap Usage issue

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, database-migration, dms

I have created AWS DMS Replication Task which is stuck at 70% with a message in log, the task used to run smoothly before and have been stuck for the last week.

```
2021-01-13T12:19:20:148589 [TASK_MANAGER    ]D:  Swap usage stats not available yet  (replicationtask_cmd.c:1625)
```

I have checked Replication Instance Swap Memory and I see no usage of it in cloudformation at all, I have increased Source DB RAM so that there is no issue there, not sure which swap usage this is referring to. Please help debug this

Answer (score 1):

**Answer: This was a swap issue in the Target DB and not in Replication Instance/Source DB**

Comment: What if my target is S3?

Comment: I got the answer by reaching out to AWS Support, for DMS they will provide extended reply on that, swap usage for S3 should generally not be unavailable as it is managed by Amazon itself, however if it is indeed the case most probably it will be because of limitations of your AWS account and support will reply accordingly

Comment: Having the same issue but cloudwatch is not showing a swap usage being overused, its at 50mb